# Insert string into different tables based on combobox selection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

1st off, my apologies if this question has been asked. I have looked but haven't found an exact answer to the problem I'm facing. Secondly, **I must stress that, I am not a developer**, I'm an engineer and only writing sowftware as a needs must situation.

I have a form which passes data to an access db (This works). However I need to update it so that it will pass the information to different tables within the same db based upon a selection in a combobox. For instance if combobox selection = X then insert into tableX, if combobox = Y then insert into tableY. Any and all help is appreciated.

I've tried using If statements in order to select the appropriate table, but this doesn't work.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Public ds As New DataSet
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim rs As New resizer
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand


Private con As Object

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "R:\Quality\NCR-Access_Database\NCRdb1.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()



    Dim str As String
    str = ""

    If ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Assembly" Then
        str = "Insert into [ASSEMBLYtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Grinding" Then
        str = "Insert into [GRINDINGtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Milling" Then
        str = "Insert into [MILLINGtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Mill-Turn" Then
        str = "Insert into [MILL-TURNtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Turning" Then
        str = "Insert into [TURNINGtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Supplier" Then
        str = "Insert into [PURCHASINGtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Subcon" Then
        str = "Insert into [PURCHASINGtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedText = "Quality" Then
        str = "Insert into [QUALITYtbl]([NCR-No],[Week-No],[Part-No],[Drawing-Rev],[Description],[W/O-Number],[Operator-No],[Operation-No],[Machine-No],[Section],[Batch-Qty],[Reject_Qty],[Disposition],[Mat-Cost],[Standard-Cost],[Defect-Descripition],[Fault-Code],[Dept],[Root-Cause],[NCR-Pinksheet],[Action]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    End If


    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NCR-No", TextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Week-No", TextBox3.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Part-No", TextBox4.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Drawing_Rev", TextBox5.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Description", TextBox6.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("W/O-No", TextBox7.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Operator-No", TextBox8.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Operation-No", TextBox9.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Machine-No", TextBox10.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Section", ComboBox2.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Batch-Qty", TextBox12.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Reject_Qty", TextBox13.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Disposition", TextBox14.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Mat-Cost", TextBox15.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Standard-Cost", TextBox16.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Defect-Description", RichTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Fault-Code", TextBox17.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Dept", TextBox18.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Root-Cause", RichTextBox2.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NCR-Pinksheet", ComboBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Permanent-Action", RichTextBox3.Text))

    Try

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
        TextBox7.Clear()
        TextBox8.Clear()
        TextBox9.Clear()
        TextBox10.Clear()
        ComboBox2.ResetText()
        TextBox12.Clear()
        TextBox13.Clear()
        TextBox14.Clear()
        TextBox15.Clear()
        TextBox16.Clear()
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox17.Clear()
        TextBox18.Clear()
        RichTextBox2.Clear()
        ComboBox1.ResetText()
        RichTextBox3.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


End Class
```

When submitting I get a dialog that states "Command text was not set for the command object". If i submit again, then I get an exception unhandled event in VS --- "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is open.'"

Comment: Where are you adding the required parameters to the Command? How are you executing the Command? Did you close the connection at some point (better, declare it with a `Using` statement)? -- You could fill your ComboBox with both the informations: the *friendly* table name (`Assembly`) and the actual table name (`ASSEMBLYtbL`), so you can use the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to set the selected table, removing all the if conditions (if, as it looks like, the fields names are the same. Otherwise, you could retrive (or store) the table structure based on the selection or use predefined strings).

Comment: The command parameters are after the if statements, connection isn't closed. My combobox is populated with the friendly name of assembly etc.. So not certain exactly what you mean.  (yes all fields are the same in each table.) I've added the rest of the code for reference. (_The field names are named appropriatley in the if statements_) I've only shortented it for space in on here.

Comment: The connection is closed: `myConnection.Close()`, but not disposed of. Where is `cmd` defined (you should declare it in the same *place*, in a `Using` statement, the same for the connection)? Are the field names actually `field1`, `field2` etc.? Or `NCR-No`, `Week-No` etc.? Is the field corresponding to the `NCR-No` parameter actually a text field, etc.? Are the fields in the correct order, the same as the parameters?

Comment: About the ComboBox: this control can store a complex object, not just strings. You can use a list of combined values (two strings, in this case), then retrive the one you need when the *paired* string is selected in the Control. So, when `Assembly` is selected, you can read `ASSEMBLYtbL`. See the [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember) and [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember) properties.

Comment: Oh it is closed, I didn't see that... Disposed of?? do you mean `myConnection.Dispose`  cmd is defined in a code block above my sub. The fields are actually called Ncr-No etc. I was using this exact code minus the `if` statements to pass the data to one table, but soon realised I would need that data sending to seperate tables hence the change.

Comment: Didn't you call `cmd.Dispose()`? Well, this also applies to `myConnection`: `myConnection.Dispose()`. See the [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) usage (and sample code). The fields' names in the Command must match those in the database. The parameters must be presented in the same order as the fields (parameter in ms-access are positional, their name is irrelevant). Declare and dispose of the Command in the same piece of code where you declare and use the connection.

Comment: No, I didn't use `cmd.Dispose` didn't realise I had to. As stated in my original question. I'm not a developer, so this is all quite new to me. I've added my full code above, so you can see exactly how it's working. I will look into the using statement and see if that makes sense.  Will try more tomorrow, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you did. Right after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: I meant `myConnection.Dispose` _sorry_

Answer (score 0):

## use INSERT INTO syntax

```
INSERT INTO table-name (column-names) 
VALUES (values)
```

## SQL INSERT INTO with SELECT like this

```
INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName, City, Country, Phone)
SELECT LEFT(ContactName, CHARINDEX(' ',ContactName) - 1), 


SUBSTRING(ContactName, CHARINDEX(' ',ContactName) + 1, 100),
  City, Country, Phone
 FROM Supplier
 WHERE CompanyName = 'casterx.co'
```